# Ruby cutting off 0 decimal if it is the last decimal

Tags: arrays, ruby, parsing, floating-point

I am taking a binary string and decoding it into an array of floats.  I have that part figured out.

I now have to take that array and format it with three decimal places left on, with NO rounding. All my numbers are correct, but for whatever reason if the third decimal place is a 0, then Ruby cuts it off, and I need those 0s included.

For example:

Expected:

```
3.480
```

My output:

```
3.48
```

How can I truncate a floating point number to three decimal places and if that number ends in 0, how can I keep that zero from being cut off?

```
f.each_line do |line|
  if first
    first = false
  else
    a, b, c = line.chop.split(',')
    # puts a,b,c
    ay = Base64.decode64(c)
    ay = ay.unpack('f*')
    ay.each do |x|
      temp = ((x * 1000).floor / 1000.0) #error occurs here
      puts temp
      o.write(temp.to_s + ',')
    end
  end

end

f.close
```

Comment: Numbers don't have trailing zeros: trailing decimal 0s don't change the value. Text representing them might - how does Ruby let you *format* numbers as strings? (There are sooo many duplicates..)

Answer (score 4):

The zero doesn't get "cut off", it's just not shown in the output. If you want a certain level of precision you need to ask for it:

```
o.write(ay.collect { |v| '%.3f' % v }.join(','))
```

This handles both rounding and presentation in one shot. If you just want rounding you should use the [`round`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Float.html#method-i-round) function:

```
v.round(3)
```

Remember that internally your floating point numbers are stored in binary, so there's no such thing as 2.30. Internally that might be 2.29999999998371923891, but that gets cleaned up when presented as a string.

Comment: So I tried utilizing this but now some of my numbers are rounding up, and what I want is the floating point number up to the third decimal place.

Comment: They'll have to get rounded, but the way they get rounded is up to you. Do you have examples of the sorts of numbers you're dealing with?

Comment: I just need to take each number in the array and cut it off at the third decimal place. Is there a way I can do that with string formatting? Because I can't round these.

Comment: Floating point numbers must be treated as approximations, that's how they behave, and they don't have any intrinsic formatting. The only way you get formatting is by converting to a string, and when that happens you'll have to deal with rounding, there is no way around it. You can pick a rounding strategy that fits your requirements, like truncation, if that's preferable. There's a lot of methods in the [Float](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Float.html#method-i-coerce) library to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, if you want your number to be truncated (not rounded) to three decimal places, then:

```
n = 3.14159265358979
puts "%.3f" % ((n*1000).floor / 1000.0)
#=> 3.141
```

What this does:

```
n*1000                     # 3141.59265358979
(n*1000).truncate          # 3141
(n*1000).truncate / 1000.0 # 3.141
```

I then use the [`"%.3f"` formatting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) along with the [`%` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) to ensure that exactly three decimal places are shown (even if some of them are trailing zeros).

If you use this often, or need to use it generically:

```
class Numeric
  def truncate_to( digits=0 )
    factor = 10.0**digits
    "%.#{digits}f" % ((self*factor).truncate / factor)
  end
end

puts [ 3.14159, 1, -1.9999 ].map{ |n| n.truncate_to(3) }
#=> 3.141
#=> 1.000
#=> -1.999
```